# How to mock decorator in django unit test?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, mocking

I am trying to write simple unit test for my view. I have a decorator which authenticate by sending http request. How to mock decorator of my view and run unit test?

my **views.py**

```
@method_decorator(authentication_decorator, name='post')
class AddBlogView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (adapt the code for your app and file names):

```py
from mock import patch
patch('app.decorators.authentication_decorator', lambda x: x).start()  # This line must come before other imports

from app.views import AddBlogView
# Test AddBlogView
```

Comment: Odd that it needs to be so high up in the file, but it works... Any idea why?

Comment: @Anthony With `patch` you  replace the decorator with a function that basically does nothing (that is always successful), so that you don't have to send http requests (in this case) and can easily performs unit tests. The use of `patch` must precede the import of the other classes, because otherwise they will use the real decorator and not the mocked one. The mocked decorator is used only by classes imported after the `patch`, so all the classes that have to do with the decorator have to come next